# Gnome stop working after add a SSD

Tags: gnome, ssd

I'm using the Ubuntu 20.04. Today, I added a second SSD NVME and the system stopped to boot. The screen was just showing a blinking cursor.

After dig a bit, I noticed i was able to use the virtual consoles (ttys). In the tty, both SSD drives are recognized and I can access them without any problem.

Doing another couple of tests, I realize that the problem with Gnome happens just when I use a specific M.2 slot. It doesn't matter which SSD I plug into that slot, the Gnome stops working (although I can use the drive on tty)

So far was able to verify that:

1. Both SSD devices are working
2. Both M2 slots are working
3. When using a particular M.2 slot, I can't start the graphical system

Any ideas of what is happen or what I can try to make both SSDs work ? I'm kind of lost here :(

Thank you

Comment: Check your motherboard manual. Often NVMe drive disables a SATA port. And some M.2 ports only support certain features. Do you have different video drivers installed on each drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simpler than I thought... =/
When using multiple NVME drives, GPUs addresses are (in some way) changed.
All I had to do to make Gnome work was run `nvidia-xconfig` again (since I'm using nvidia video cards)